# where is the user id in my emailjs account?

Tags: reactjs, email, userid

earlier it is there used to be an integration tab in the left menu from where we could've taken user-id. now that option itself is not there. I searched in 'personal account' option and 'account' option and all the other options but I couldn't find any user id in this. I require user id to set up email for my react application

[![emailjs page after login in ][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcKZ6.png

Answer (score 4):

update: emailJS removed the integration tab, and now replaced userid with public key which can be found in 'account'

Answer (score 1):

Correct answer and to reiterate what was said ! email-js removed the "user-Id"  value from the dashboard. And user-Id has now been replaced by "public key" which is found under the account section on the email.js dashboard.
Your contact form should now be sending email using emailjs. When the user submits the form, the handleSubmit function will send an email to your designated email address with the form data.